# How to apply distinct on google datastore using objectify?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, distinct, objectify

I am trying to fetch some entities with distinct values on a property. Say, I have an entity called messages. And it has some properties say personId, typeId, convId, createdTime, etc. I want fetch messages of personId p1 with distinct convIds. How can I do that.

I already referred to 
[Executing DISTINCT query with objectify for app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32938795/executing-distinct-query-with-objectify-for-app-engine)
and some others. And tried something like this.

```
ofy().load().type(messages.class).limit( 10 ).filter("personId ==", "p1").order("-createdTime").project("convId").distinct(true).list();
```

I am sure that there are some entities with this combination. But it is fetching no entities.
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your query isn't valid.  For projection queries you need `distinct` to be on the values that you are sorting by (i.e. -createdTime).  To use distinct you'll need to order by convId.

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#restrictions_on_queries has more details.